# How can I cross compile Rust code into Intel assembly on an ARM M1 Apple Silicon Mac?

Tags: macos, rust, x86-64, cross-compiling

I've been comparing the assembly code generated by C and Rust for x86 and ARM.

I have an M1 Mac and I found how to cross-compile C with Clang, but so far I can't find how to cross-compile Rust.

How can I generate an x86_64 binary from Rust on an M1 Mac?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Cross-compilation is built in, just use `rustup` to install the target support:

```
$ rustup target install x86_64-apple-darwin
```

and build your crate like this:

```
$ cargo build --target x86_64-apple-darwin
```

Thanks to Rosetta you can even run it like this:

```
$ cargo run --target x86_64-apple-darwin
```

Comment: How about cross compilation to a x86-64 linux machine? I have been searching for this could find it yet. This toolchain cannot be installed on m1 machine : `brew install filosottile/musl-cross/musl-cross`

Comment: @srknzl See https://github.com/messense/homebrew-macos-cross-toolchains

Comment: First, this is a great and concise answer. 

@srknzl My current plan to compile linux x86 on M1, is to use docker (for both aarch64 and x64).

Comment: @HHK That didn't help me, I kept getting linker errors.

Comment: @HHK Also having linker errors

Comment: @dimitarvp: This is likely a separate issue. Please open a new question and link it in a comment here.

Comment: @FrankNicklin: This is likely a separate issue. Please open a new question and link it in a comment here.